# Dialogflow conv: body.session vs request.conversation.conversationId?

Tags: actions-on-google

Am currently having to convert my agent to a conv to get past review stage of an app.  I can find no details on whether `conv.body.session` should be used to identify a conversation or `conv.request.conversation.conversationId`.

Can anyone provide any information on the difference or preferences?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `conversationId`. Check out [this](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/reference/webhook/rest/Shared.Types/AppRequest#conversation) reference.